# Php zend framework forcedownload

Tags: php, header

I should set up a simple download manager
and I don't understand whay this code doesn't work:

```
protected function doDownload($filename){
        //$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        //$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        $dir = Zend_Registry::get('dir');
        $file = $dir->assets.$filename;
        if(file_exists($file)){
            $response = $this->getResponse();
            $response->setHeader('Content-Description','File Transfer', true);
            $response->setHeader('Content-Type','application/octet-stream', true);
            $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='.basename($file), true);
            $response->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding','binary', true);
            $response->setHeader('Expires','0', true);
            $response->setHeader('Cache-Control','must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
            $response->setHeader('Pragma','public', true);
            $response->setHeader('Content-Length: ' , filesize($file),true);
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            exit(0);
          /*header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            exit(0);*/

         }


    }
```

while with the commented code the script works fine.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive on "it doesn't work". Any errors popping up? Or is the file shown instead of downloaded?

Answer (score 5):

You basically don't perform any output through the Zend Framework (apart from your headers). Try the following :

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $this->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('Content-Description','File Transfer', true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Type','application/octet-stream', true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='.basename($file), true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding','binary', true)
        ->setHeader('Expires','0', true)
        ->setHeader('Cache-Control','must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true)
        ->setHeader('Pragma','public', true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Length: ' , filesize($file),true);
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(file_get_contents($file));
}
```

BTW You will have to comment out your first two lines of code again AND don't us exit(0), otherwise it won't work, since the actual sending of headers and body will be done post-action.

Comment: I commented out this line
 $layout = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Layout');
            $view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
            $layout->disableLayout();
            $view->setNoRender(true);
It is a plugin.

Comment: This gives a 0 byte file in Chrome. Changing the line to this made it work: ->setHeader('Content-Length', filesize($file),true);

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do not understand why your code should work? Should readfile() automatically trigger a sendHeaders() or writeHeaders() method on the $response object before the file content is output?!? I think you should call this method or use a method which calls it... like the suggested $this->getResponse->setBody() in the other answer

Comment: @Felix Kling
It shows the file instead do download it
@greg0ire
I never used the response object in this way and I didn't find any tutorial  could you show me an
example please ?